# Calendar widget on Mac showing no events

Tags: macos, calendar, notifications, widgets

I'm running macOS High Sierra on my MacBook Pro and I do have events in my calendar app. However, it is not showing any events on the calendar widget in the Notification Center. I have tried deleting cache several times but no luck.

How can I resolve this?